# How to dismiss UIViewController from UITableViewCell

Tags: swift

I need to dismiss ViewController from the corresponding TableViewCell, but I'm getting an error   message, "Value of type 'TableViewCell' has no member 'dismiss'"

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How can I dismiss the ViewController from the corresponding TableViewCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the solution and don't really care about the structure of the application, the following will work. As the other guy mentioned, this probably isn't the best way to structure your application.

Make a delegate to the TableViewCell.

```
protocol TableViewDismissDelegate {
    func dismissViewController()
}
class YourTableViewClass {
    var delegate: TableViewDismissDelegate?

    ...
}
```

In your table view delegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = mainTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: YourTableViewClass.identifier, for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewClass
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Make sure your view controller conforms to your protocol:

```
extension YourViewController: TableViewDismissDelegate {
    func dismissViewController() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just make sure to make the delegate variable `weak` or you will have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot say `self.dismiss` in a UITableViewCell, as `dismiss` is a UIViewController command, and a UITableViewCell is not a UIViewController.

---

What I like to do in this situation is *get a reference* to the UIViewController so that I can tell it to `dismiss`. To do so, I create a UIResponder extension, like this:

```
extension UIResponder {
    func next<T:UIResponder>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
        let r = self.next
        if let r = r as? T ?? r?.next(ofType: T.self) {
            return r
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

That extension just walks up the responder chain looking for an instance of any class we care to name. So now `self.next(ofType: UIViewController.self)` is the view controller, and we can tell it to `dismiss`.

(There are plenty of other solutions, but that's just a solution that I happen to like.)

---

It may be argued, however, that you should never have gotten yourself in this situation in the first place. It is no business of a UITableViewCell to be telling *anyone* to dismiss *anything*. This is a violation of model-view-controller principles. You should probably be looking at a completely different architecture here.